# Select statement processing before Where clause in view

Tags: sql, database, database-indexes

I have a statement that selects the substring of a charindex as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(StringField, 5, CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) - 5)...
WHERE 
CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5
```

When I run the above statement in a select query, the results are returned just fine. When I run the above statement in a schema bound indexed view, I get this error:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function
```

To solve the problem I will write a function to get the Max of the CharIndex and 0 as to remove the possibilities of a negative value. But does anyone know why the where clause would not be filtering out the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because order of operations behind the scenes in a query isn't guaranteed.**

I'm guessing if you check the execution plan you will see it's doing both checks in parallel - this because neither operation can use an index!

SQL needs to load every row of that field into memory anyways, so it's processing it for both criteria at the same time.

You can try `WITH (MAXDOP(1))` as a query hint to see if that keeps the issue from appearing, or you could do a subselect to force execution order:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(StringField, 5, CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) - 5)...
FROM (
      SELECT Stringfield 
      FROM Table 
      WHERE CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5
      ) as [X]
```

I had a similar issue once when I was checking to see if a field was numeric using `PATINDEX` and one of the columns in my view was converting this to an `int` - I got conversion errors because the engine was converting every row since my filters were not SARGable.

Comment: Just as an aside, Jonathan Kehayias has reported he's seen cases where even a subquery or CTE does not help the optimizer and the processing can still happen the other way around. The only workaround in those cases is to either figure out a plan that doesn't do it and use a fixed plan, or dump the subquery to a #temp table first to be sure the filtering happens first.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly workaround but you could do something like this perhaps:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(StringField VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT 'ABC'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'AAAAAAAABC';

SELECT SUBSTRING(StringField, 5, CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) - 5)
FROM @x
WHERE CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5;

SELECT SUBSTRING(StringField,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5 THEN 5 ELSE 1 END,
    CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) - 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END)
FROM @x
WHERE CHARINDEX('ABC', StringField) > 5;
```

Both yield:

```
---
AAA
```

But I suspect the latter will be allowed in your view. It's ugly but unfortunately unless you dump the filtered data to a #temp table first (or try to see if `MAXDOP` reliably removes the issue) you're not going to have much control over order of processing.

Another idea is to try putting a computed column in the table (but I'm not sure that will help if you are trying to create an indexed view - there may still be complications). Or to use a filtered index with that expression, instead of an indexed view. There could be several "solutions" if we know what the indexed view is meant to accomplish and what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: (As an aside, SQL Server is smart enough to perform the computer scalar operator only once per row, so don't think those extra charindex operations have any impact on the plan, duration, CPU, etc.)